# Adding a listener to create a warning message to a textfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, playframework, textfield

I have a combo box and a textfield. I am trying to Add a warning notifcation to the textfield stating 'please enter value' if something is selected from the combo box. However, I only want the warning to display on the textfield if '3' is selected from the combo box

Is there any way that I could do that? I am not sure how to do that.

Here is the code for my combobox and textfield:

```
{
                            xtype:'combo',
                            store: ['1','2','3'],
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            fieldLabel: 'Area',
                            id: 'dcArea',
                            width: 125,
                        },{
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Mile',
                            id: 'mile',
                            width: 125,
                        }
```

Comment: I don't usually work with extJS, so I'd suggest binding an event handler / listener to your textfield for the `change` event. Then check if that combobox holds the value `3`. If so, display your warning. Maybe there's an easier solution with extJS, but idk.

Answer (score 2):

The listener needs to be on the combo, of course. Use [`msgTarget`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-msgTarget) to customize how the error message is displayed.

```
{
    xtype:'combo',
    store: ['1','2','3'],
    triggerAction: 'all',
    fieldLabel: 'Area',
    // bad practice
    // id: 'dcArea',
    width: 150,

    // <EDIT>
    msgTarget: 'under',
    // </EDIT>

    listeners: {
        change: function(combo, value) {
            // use component query to retrieve the other field
            var textfield = this.up('form').down('#mile');
            if (value === '3') {
                textfield.markInvalid("Please enter value");
            } else {
                textfield.clearInvalid();
            }
        }
    }
},{
    xtype:'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Mile',
    itemId: 'mile',
    width: 150
}
```

**Edit** Use the [`msgTarget`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-msgTarget) property of the combo box to configure how the error message is displayed (see the updated code example).

Comment: I've tried the above method, but I am still getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: That means you've got a syntax error somewhere else in your code... It's not in what I've posted, I've tested it. The error message should point to a specific line, find the error in this line. If you can't, post your code and I'll tell you.

Comment: Right sorry, I fixed it. However, when I run the code with the listener and select the value 3 from the Area drop down and click outside of the combo box nothing happens. I do not get any textfield saying "please enter value" for the Mile textfield

Comment: The field turns red, doesn't it? By default the message appears in a tooltip when you hover the field.

Answer (score 1):

In extjs this is the way to add listeners, `on change` will be helpful in this case.
Sample:

```
              {
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Mile',
                    id: 'mile',
                    width: 125,
                    name: 'myMiles'
                    listeners: {
                         'change': function() {
                          console.log('you changed the text of this input field');
                          var value = Ext.getCmp('mile').getValues().myMiles;
                          if(value == 3)
                          {
                            alert('You selected 3');
                          }
                        }
                    }
              }
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to like the if(value == 3) function. I get an error message saying unexpected token if

Comment: @user1676428 because by mistake i added `}` before `if`. Corrected in answer.

Comment: this wont display warning on texfield